# Wireshark display filter; bitwise comparison

Tags: filter, wireshark, tshark

Given a pcap file, I would like to separate packets into four sets based on bitwise comparison on their ip.src, comparing only two specific bits in the IP. For example I would like to apply this comparison on the 2nd Byte of the IP and on the last couple of bits. Therefore, the comparison would be like the following:

```
a = xxxxxxxx & 0x03 //It is 8bits. Hence a includes 000000xx
IF (a == 0x00) THEN set0
IF (a == 0x01) THEN set1
IF (a == 0x02) THEN set2
IF (a == 0x03) THEN set3
```

Unfortunately there is only the bitwise_and option available. And I cannot do bitwise operation on the IP here. Is there any solution for this?

What I had in mind was to use the following command four times, each time using the corresponding display filter.

```
tshark -r <infile> -Y "<display-filter>" -w <outfile>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In wireshark, open the PCAP file and use the display filter like so:

```
!(ip[12] & 0x01) and !(ip[12] & 0x02)
(ip[12] & 0x01) and !(ip[12] & 0x02)
!(ip[12] & 0x01) and (ip[12] & 0x02)
(ip[12] & 0x01) and (ip[12] & 0x02)
```

The first one matches 0b00 for the last two bits, the 2nd 0b01, the 3rd 0b10 and the last matches 0b11.

If you want other bits, they will be 0x04, 0x08, 0x10, 0x20, 0x40 and 0x80 for the most significant bit. "&" is the same as bitwise_and.

After matching each one use **File -> Export Specified Packets** and ensure the option **Displayed** is marked. This is a way to split the file to 4 sets as you desire.

Comment: Thank you. It worked. I ended up using the following display filter for my application (3rd and 4th bits in the second byte from left): 
"!(ip.src[1] == 0x10) and !(ip.src[1] == 0x20)"
And repeating this style for three more times.